# Does a workaround or solution exists for the label conflict of circuitikz and TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I would like to use circuitikz with TikZ. However, I find that circuitikz modifies or does not recognize TikZ labels. The author of circuitiz has commented that in the 
["released version of CircuiTikz (0.2.3) the problem has been fixed."](http://vindsnurror.wordpress.com/2009/11/10/tikz-and-circuitikz-label-conflict/)
But the problem still exists.

Does a workaround or solution exists for the label conflict of circuitikz and tikz?

Here is a simple example using TikZ v2.10 and circuitikz v0.23. Instead of getting a resistor labeled `R1` below it, I get a resistor labeled info above it when circuitikz is active. It makes no difference which environment is used, tikzpicture or circuitikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,
    set resistor graphic    = var resistor IEC graphic]
\draw (0,0) to[resistor={info'={$R_1$}}] (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is not that Circuitikz redefines the `info` style, but that it redefines the `resistor` style, and arguments to it aren't processed as options anymore. Do you need a way to get a label below the resistor when `circuitikz` is active *and* you are in a `tikzpicture`, or could you switch to a `circuitikz` environment and use the `circuitikz` syntax of `l_=<label>` for a label?

Comment: @xport. I just discovered your comment! So, thanks for the clarification regarding the redefinition that `circuitikz` makes with `resistor` style. I thought that `tikz` and `circuitikz` could be used interchangeably with ease. Not, so by my experience. However, I do appreciate some of the features of the `circuitikz` syntax like `l_=<label>`.

Comment: @zun: I don't know much about TikZ. I use PSTricks. The comment does not belong to me. :-)

Comment: I prefer to use the `circuits` library of `TikZ` (version 2.10). I find it's much nicer than `circuitikz`. :)

Comment: @Jake: Could you provide an answer based on the additional information in zun's comment from Aug 17 (that was wrongly directed at xport)?

Comment: I have most of a solution for this, which hinges on a macro inside the `to[...]` part. `circuitikz` has no problem expanding it, but in normal TikZ I get a compilation error. Anyone know a way around this?

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt I think you might want to start a fresh question with your partial answer. That would be much more informative. Maybe also this one can be closed as a duplicate (don't know if possible chronologically though).

Comment: @Jake A belated apology for incorrectly attributing your comment to someone else. Lately, I prefer to use tikz and circuitikz packages, but do all my circuit *work* in the tikzpicture environment.

Comment: @percusse: Will do. Snowed under at the moment, so I'll aim to write something up this evening UTC+9.

Comment: The author just introduced a `compatibility` switch. So if you get the preview from here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147491/10117 , your MWE is OK by using `\usepackage[compatibility]{circuitikz}`.

Answer (score 4):

While to late, for future people stumbling across this, when deciding between *tikz's circiuts* and *circuitikz*, one does no have to choose anymore, since a package option `compatability` was added, that prefixes  all `circuitikz` styles with an asterisk `*`.

From the [circuitikz manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf)

> TikZ’s own circuit library, which is based on CircuiTikZ, (re?)defines
>   several styles used by this library. In order to have them work
>   together I added the compatibility package option, which basically
>   prefixes the names of all CircuiTikZ to[] styles with an asterisk

Answer (score 1):

Though I have not found a direct workaround or solution to my original question regarding the label conflict between **tikz** and **circuitikz**, I have been using the following method for many months. Others, I'm certain, use the same idea, as it's based on the circuitikz manual. I use the **circuitikz** (and **tikz**) package, but rely principally on the circuitikz library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[siunitx,european,american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to[R,l_=$R_1$] (2,0);
\draw (0,1) to[R,l=$R_2$]  (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```