# Tikz US-style components and other components

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, tikz-circuit-lib

In circuittikz there is a full library of US-style components like the +/- voltage source, directed arrow current source, etc.

As far as I can tell from the documentation, the Tikz circuit library has US resistors (`var resistor IEC graphic`) and US-style logic symbols, but I can't find the other symbols.

Also, the Tikz documentation doesn't seem to have any references to transistor symbols (in particular BJT's and MOSFETS), amplifiers, triacs, and many of the non-basic symbols found in circuitikz.

Does anyone know of a pre-compiled list of shapes/components designed to be compatible with the Tikz circuit library and uses similar syntax forms? This is not including the circuitikz shapes, from what I understand these libraries aren't [completely compatible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33660/relationship-between-tikz-circuit-library-and-circuitikz).

Comment: You should be able to use the shapes from `circuitikz` in TikZ (without its syntax or mechanisms to place them). You only need to find out what the shape is named. (I think there is a paragraph in the `ciruitikz` manual that explains it.)

Comment: Circuitikz definitly has also other different symbols namely `European style`. Please read the manual again. http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf

Comment: @WG- I know circuitikz has both US and European/IEC styles, my question was about the Tikz circuit library. It sounds like I can use the shapes from circuitikz with Tikz circuit library, or end up having to write my own shapes if I want full support with the Tikz circuit library.

Comment: @helloworld922 okay sorry then I misinterpret your question. But please be more specific because from `...but I can't find the other symbols.` `Do they exist? If so, how do I use them in place of the IEC symbols?`it is really not clear what you wanted. But no Tikz circuit, not circuittikz, does not have any other symbols then the ones you will find in the documentation. If you want others you will have to create them for yourself.

Comment: I suppose more specifically my question was about whether someone has already compiled symbols specifically so I can use them with tikz circuits library. I'll update my question appropriately.

Comment: So, what symbols do you want?

Comment: You do realize that Circuitikz is layered on top of Tikz, and that everything in the Tikz library is still available from Circuitikz (resistor instead of R, diode instead of full diode, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Since I prefer **Tikz** over **Circuitikz** I have to cope with this problem too.
I use to define these shapes (and some others) in all of my documents. I can't remember where I found the voltage source one.

```
%+/- voltage source
\tikzset{circuit declare symbol = var voltage source}
\tikzset{set var voltage source graphic = var voltage source IEC graphic}
\tikzset{
  var voltage source IEC graphic/.style={
    circuit symbol lines,
    circuit symbol size = width 2 height 2,
    shape=generic circle IEC,
    /pgf/generic circle IEC/before background={
     \pgfgettransform\savedtransform
     \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0.05\tikzcircuitssizeunit}{0\tikzcircuitssizeunit}}
     \pgftransformresetnontranslations
     \pgftransformscale{0.1\tikzcircuitssizeunit}
     \pgftext{$+$}
     \pgfsettransform\savedtransform
     \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{-0.06\tikzcircuitssizeunit}{0\tikzcircuitssizeunit}}
     \pgftransformresetnontranslations
     \pgftransformscale{0.1\tikzcircuitssizeunit}
     \pgftext{$-$}
     \pgfsettransform\savedtransform
    },
    transform shape
  }
}
%Arrow current source
\tikzset{circuit declare symbol = var current source}
\tikzset{set var current source graphic = var current source IEC graphic}
\tikzset{
  var current source IEC graphic/.style={
    circuit symbol lines,
    circuit symbol size = width 2 height 2,
    shape=generic circle IEC,
    /pgf/generic circle IEC/before background={
      \pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.1\tikzcircuitssizeunit}{0}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.1\tikzcircuitssizeunit}{0}}
      \pgfusepath{stroke}
    },
    transform shape
  }
}
```