# Joining points smoothly with previously defined paths - e.g. for use with .pics

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to join a point defined in a previously defined path smoothly - like the command circle does. I boiled it down to a MWE, but the background are bigger drawings and especially reuse of code through .pic

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\tikzset%
{%
        geometry/.pic=%
        {%
                  \coordinate (-A) at (0,0);
                  \coordinate (-B) at (2,1);
                  \draw (-A) -| (-B);
        }%
}%
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width = 3pt]
  %% FIRST EXAMPLE %%
  \pic (GEO) {geometry};
  \draw (GEO-A) -- (GEO-B);
%
  %% FIRST EXAMPLE %%
  \coordinate (C) at (3,0);
  \coordinate (D) at (5,1);
  \draw (C) -| (D);
  \draw (C) -- (D);
%
  %% SECOND EXAMPLE %%
  \coordinate (E) at (6,0);
  \coordinate (F) at (8,1);
  \draw (E) -| (F) -- cycle;
%
  %% THIRD EXAMPLE %%
  \draw[red] (GEO-A) circle [radius = 8pt];
  \draw[red] (GEO-B) circle [radius = 8pt];
  \draw[red] (C) circle [radius = 8pt];
  \draw[red] (D) circle [radius = 8pt];
  \draw[green] (E) circle [radius = 8pt];
  \draw[green] (F) circle [radius = 8pt];
%
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

The FIRST EXAMPLE with coordinates A & B shows, how I want to structure the code, the SECOND EXAMPLE proofs, that this is not a problem of the usage of .pic. The THIRD EXAMPLE shows how, I want the result to look like, but the way of coding it is not applicable in for reuse of code and in bigger drawings.

The red circles in the following picture show the problem, the green circle show the result I want to get (preferable with the use of .pic as in the FIRST EXAMPLE).

Any ideas?

[image: RED is BAD, GREEN is GOOD]

Comment: 1. If you use `line cap=round,line join=round` there will be no problem. 2. The library `circuits`, by its nature, has to deal with this issue. You can either (2a) declare your `.pic` as a electronic component using this library; or (2b) learn from its source code.

Comment: to have "connected" lines on shape you had not to draw as separated segments. For details see *TikZ & PGF manual*, page 148.

Comment: Thx for your inputs. @Symbol1: using (1) `\draw[line cap=round] (GEO-A) -- (GEO-B);` and `\draw[line cap=round] (C) -- (D);` respectively is an acceptable solution. The joints are still **rounded** and not **mitter**, which was what I intended to do in the first place. (2a) is a potential way to go, however I use **circuitikz** already and combining it with the **circuit library** can relate in compatibility issues like [link] https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33660/relationship-between-tikz-circuit-library-and-circuitikz and others. (2b) would solve this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in the comments.