# Circuitikz symbols in TikZ circuit library

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, tikz-circuit-lib

Some time ago, I asked about [Relationship between tikz circuit library and circuitikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33660/relationship-between-tikz-circuit-library-and-circuitikz/33662#33662). wh1t3 wrote: "However, as far as I know there is nothing the `circuitikz` package does that the TikZ `circuit` library can't."

So if it is true that the tikz library is more powerful, how do I get all the symbols described in the [`circuitikz` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/latex/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf) using the TikZ circuit library?

Especially I am missing the symbols for ammeters and voltmeters.

Comment: You'll probably have to build them. You van use as a starting point the symbol for voltage source and tinker around with it.

Comment: I have just found this discussion: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=998588.27363.qm%40web120711.mail.ne1.yahoo.com&forum_name=pgf-users

Answer (score 3):

This is like a short cut which saves from building symbols afresh from `tikz circuit library`. If you do not mind using `circuitikz`, there is a way you can use those symbols inside `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,parskip]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz} %<------------ 
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
%=======================
\begin{document}
%======================
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to[voltmeter] (2,0);
\draw (0,1) to[ammeter] (2,1);
\draw (3,0) node [ground] {};
\draw (0,2) to[american voltage source] (2,2);
\draw (4.2,0.5) to[sI=$a_1$] (4.2,2.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
%========================
\end{document}
```

You may notice that here `\begin{circuitikz}....\end{circuitikz}` is not used. But the circuitikz symbols  are accessible through `\usepackage{circuitikz}`. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: There are some problems about mixing the two, [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19504/) is a sample of it.

Comment: @percusse, I accept. Thanks for noting it. But this is a short cut where both the libraries should not be mixed. I mean one should use only circuitikz libraries.

Comment: Notice that as per now (2022) there is a compatibility mode in circuitos, even if it's not recommended.