# circuit tikz library with relative paths breaks LED

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-circuit-lib

Using circuits library with relative paths breaks the LED for me. Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
        %broken
        \draw (-2,0) to [diode={light emitting}] +(0,4);
        %ok
        \draw (0,0) to [diode={light emitting}] (0,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

unexpected result:

[image: result]

Is there any way to use relative paths with circuit library in tikz?

Comment: Not the optimal solution but add another `+`.

Comment: @percusse Ok I looked it up, and `+` is a valid operator. *puh* ;)

Comment: I would say this is a bug though.

Comment: hmm. Looks like a SF account is needed for bug reports. Anyway thx for the workaround!

Comment: You might try Circuitikz, which is just Tikz with some additional definitions (not an evil clone).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `circle declare annotation`s are setup differently, it works. They use originally the `++` operator. I re-defined them so that they use the `shift`ing.

Here I am using an auxiliary coordinate named `@`. If this is wanted to be avoided one can substitute the start of the path so that it will be evaluated twice but the `@` coordinate (and its macros) is not used.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\tikzset{
  circuit declare annotation={light emitting}{1.75\tikzcircuitssizeunit}
  {
    (+-.2\tikzcircuitssizeunit,+.65\tikzcircuitssizeunit) coordinate (@) edge[line to] ([shift=(45:+1.25\tikzcircuitssizeunit)] @)
    ( +.2\tikzcircuitssizeunit,+.25\tikzcircuitssizeunit) coordinate (@) edge[line to] ([shift=(45:+1.25\tikzcircuitssizeunit)] @)
  },
  circuit declare annotation={light dependent}{1.75\tikzcircuitssizeunit}
  {
    [shift=(135:1.25\tikzcircuitssizeunit)]
    ( +.2\tikzcircuitssizeunit,+.65\tikzcircuitssizeunit) coordinate (@) edge[line to] ([shift=(-45:+1.25\tikzcircuitssizeunit)] @)
    (+-.2\tikzcircuitssizeunit,+.25\tikzcircuitssizeunit) coordinate (@) edge[line to] ([shift=(-45:+1.25\tikzcircuitssizeunit)] @)
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
  \draw (-2,0) to [diode={light emitting}] +(0,4) to [diode=light dependent] +(1,3);
  \draw (0,0)  to [diode={light emitting}]  (0,4) to [diode=light dependent]  (1,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[circuit ee IEC]
        %broken
        \draw (-2,0) to [diode={light emitting}] +(0,4);
        %ok
        \draw (0,0) to [diode={light emitting}] (0,4);
        %circuitikz
        \draw (2,0) to [leDo] +(0,4);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I decided to leave this here simply do demonstrate that Circuitikz and the Tikz circuit library are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Sure. Just be aware that the current version is conflicting [1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19504/does-a-workaround-or-solution-exists-for-the-label-conflict-of-circuitikz-and-ti),[2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147486/can-i-use-the-circuitikz-tripole-shapes-without-loading-the-complete-circuitikz), Next version will probably include a `compatible` [switch](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147491/10117).